# Is there a taxonomy of adversarial attacks?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, adversarial-ml, healthcare, taxonomy

I am a medical doctor working on methodological aspects of health-oriented ML. Reproducibility, replicability, generalisability are critical in this area. Among many questions, some are raised by adversarial attacks (AA).

My question is to be considered from a literature review point of view: suppose I want to check an algorithm from an AA point of view:

- is there a systematic methodology approach to be used, relating format of the data, type of models, and AA? Conceptually, is there a taxonomy of AA? If so, practically, are some AA considered as gold standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already a couple of papers in the literature that attempt to provide a taxonomy and survey of **adversarial attacks**. I will just list the two that I think are reliable enough that you can probably use as a reference.

- [A taxonomy and survey of attacks against machine learning](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1574013718303289) (2019) by Nikolaos Pitropakis et al., published in [Computer Science Review](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/computer-science-review/about/aims-and-scope)
- [Adversarial Examples: Attacks and Defenses for Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.07107.pdf) (2019) by Xiaoyong Yuan et al., published in [IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks and Learning Systems](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/RecentIssue.jsp?punumber=5962385).

Needless to say, there are different adversarial attacks, such as the [Fast Gradient Signed Method (FGSM)](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/adversarial_fgsm), and they can be classified into different categories, such as **evasion attacks** or **poising attacks**. You can find a lot more info in these cited papers.